# SASM program parameters to debugger

Tags: linux, assembly, parameters

I have installed a SASM on linux, I want to input parameters to starting program and observe registers behavior, but I don't now how input this paramteres to SASM debugger or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start debug program, in "GDB Command" on the bottom just type "run arg1 arg2 arg3..."

Answer (score -1):

another way is to put the command line arguments in the input box
and use char zz[100] ;
then :
get(zz) will read all args (except arg[0]  ) into zz and you will haave to
parse the string yourself

Comment: That's another way to get input, but it would be from stdin not command line.

Comment: To be fair, the question just asks for "parameters" or "input", so this answer could work if it didn't call them "args", especially "command line arguments".